# How do I make GitLab delete old backups?

Tags: backup, git, gitlab

I use the rake task to create backups for GitLab 6.8.2.

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` I added the following line:

```
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 60
```

This is supposed to prune backups older than 60 seconds. My expectation was that a second run of `gitlab:backup:create` would remove the first backup if 60 seconds have passed. Though the last line in the output is

> Deleting old backups ... skipping

How do I configure GitLab to actually remove old backups?

Comment: can you provide a `ls -ls` in the dir with the backups and also the output of the `date` command

Comment: You possibly forgot to `gitlab-ctl reconfigure && gitlab-ctl restart` your installation?

Answer (score 20):

The option you want is `gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time']`. I had to

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

after setting it for it to have any effect.  Note that it will only affect local backups, not Amazon-AWS S3 if you're using that.

There was [an issue with them being ignored](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1453), but I'm not sure what versions it affects.  Version 6 is pretty old. If you're on the omnibus, it might be worth an upgrade.

Comment: +1 for mentioning what (most likely) was the solution (`gitlab-ctl reconfigure`)

Comment: Would be worth mentioning that after updating `gitlab.rb` and running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` creating a new backup or when the next backup is run, expired backups will be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you are looking at rotating out stale files in the *remote* or `backup_upload_connection` folder. Gitlab is not able to remove stale backups from this or any other *remote* locations. The `backup_keep_time` is only for its internal `backup_path` which is defaulted to `/var/opt/gitlab/backups`.

I am planning to run a cron job separately which deletes all but 10 of the newest files in my remote, NFS mounted, backup folder.

```
ls -dt */ | tail -n +11 | xargs rm -rf
```

See this merge request:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1453

And this diff:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/5567/diffs

```
Note that the `backup_keep_time` configuration option only manages local
files. GitLab does not automatically prune old files stored in a third-party
object storage (e.g. AWS S3) because the user may not have permission to list
and delete files. We recommend that you configure the appropriate retention
policy for your object storage. For example, you can configure [the S3 backup
policy here as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553070/gitlab-omnibus-delete-backup-from-amazon-s3).
```